# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError for Junit parameterized tests

Tags: java, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

I am trying to add some parameterized tests to my Spring Boot app and I am running into the below error. I have added the Maven dependency but I am still recieving this error ? Am i missing something ? I have read from other posts that the version may be wrong, however I believe I am using the correct version.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext.getConfigurationParameter(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/function/Function;)Ljava/util/Optional;

```
    at org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTestExtension.provideTestTemplateInvocationContexts(ParameterizedTestExtension.java:76)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.lambda$execute$0(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:102)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

Here is the dependency I have added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciated :) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I recently had this exact same problem in a Kotlin based project that included a dependency on `kotlin-test-junit5`. I added a dependency on `junit-jupiter` version `5.9.1` and thought that this would bring in all other jUnit5 dependencies - it did not, because `kotlin-test-junit5` had already brought some older versions of some of the dependencies.

There are two solutions: either explicitly depend on `-api`, `-engine` and `-params` specifying the desired version, or specifying exlcusions on `kotlin-test-junit5`.

So instead of:

```xml
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.20</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Specify either:

```xml
   <dependencyManagement>
        <!-- Use the JUnit BOM for version management -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
   </dependencyManagement>

   <dependencies>
       ...
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.20</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
```

Or specify:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.20</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Otherwise `junit-jupiter-api` and `junit-jupiter-engine` will be overridden to version 5.6.0 from `kotlin-test-junit5`.

Personally I find the second solution cleaner and easier to maintain but that's a matter of personal preference.

NB: In the first fix you could omit either the `junit-jupiter` parent dependency, or the explicit dependency on `junit-jupiter-params`, to save a few lines of XML. I know.

Comment: Thanks, Tim, for your explanation. You helped me to solve the issue for me. As a simplification, I used your last approach without the exclusions. It works for me. In simple words: first my POM includes dependency 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.2', after that follows dependency 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5:1.8.0'.

Comment: This answer worked well for me, but then I realized that I didn't need the `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5` because `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter` contained all the basic assertions methods my proejct needed, so I just removed it altogether.

Comment: @cavpollo Indeed you can just remove it if you do not need it! In fact I'm not sure I actually use any of it myself but it is automatically added, and causing this conflict.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into a similar issue, I resolved this by ensuring maven surefire plugin was version 3.0.0

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: I'm running into this issue now and I'm not yet managing to resolve it. I've made sure that maven-surefire and maven-failsafe plugins are at latest version. 3.0.0-M7 at the moment, but the error does not go away.

The very vexing thing is, that it does work in another project, a much bigger project, and that I never had problems before until now.

I don't see what is materially different between the large project, and the new smaller project.

Exactly the same exception. Junit 5.9.1.

Comment: Eventually solved the problem in my project after I realised that Kotlin brought in an older version of some jUnit5 dependencies, and so I had to explicitly depend on all parts of jUnit5 and not just the "master" `junit-jupiter` dependency.